# Show SIM Card contacts only

Tags: sim-card

**Does anyone know if Android 8 has an option on the Contacts app to show SIM Card contacts only?** I'm gonna buy a new phone soon, and I almost forgot about this part. So I wanted to be sure before I decide to buy anything.

The explanation for what you're probably gonna ask is that I don't want the contacts in the phone itself, because if it'll be like my first smartphone, if I had the contacts on it, I'd have killed myself infinite times (the same times I formatted it). Having them on my account is out of question. No mixing contacts. What a mess. Plus having all my Gmail contacts on the Contacts app on which I want ONLY phone contacts. Nope.

An idea a person told me hours ago was to create an account specifically for that. Actually never had thought on that one. Though, I'd still like to have the contacts on my SIM card and see them through it. No copying to the phone, or I'll forget to copy some or create some in the phone without realizing and then when I format it hoping everything is on the SIM, I've just lost some new contacts. No.... So either showing all SIM contacts, or a specific Google account only for phone contacts (which is a bit stupid, but it's the best solution I've got without being able to see SIM contacts directly).

In any case. Does anyone know if the option exists on Android 8? (the phone I'm wanting comes with Oreo) At most I know it exists at least up to Lollipop 5.1, which is the one I have now - OnePlus X, so basically almost AOSP ROM with Google original apps, so Google didn't remove the feature on 5.1. Next I'm gonna buy is a Blackview, which I think it's basically AOSP too, so Samsung phones I'm not sure if they count on this because Samsung mods infinitely their phones.

**PS: Because of what I just said, if you answer, please say your phone brand (model too?). Preferably would be phones with ROMs very near to AOSP. I got to know hours ago that Samsung doesn't have the option on Android 9 and 10, but Huawei does on 9 (no idea about other brands/versions).**

Thanks in advance!

How I do it in my current phone, as a reference, is (resolution reduced to take less space here):

[image]

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, it doesn't exist. Your friend's suggestion of a new account is good

Comment: May be you are asking thew wrong question. The ability to show SIM-contacts only is AFAIK not part of Android, but is a modification by the manufacturer of your device. Hence you should ask specific if the phone model you want to buy has this feature.

Comment: Wait, the option is not from Google?? I thought it was Google's decision to include that option or not on the Contacts apps! (Then manufacturers could remove it or not, depending if they wanted or not) All the 3 phones I've had so far (ZTE, Huawei and OnePlus) have had the option there. Then I hear there are phones without it and that they're newer, so I thought it was related to Google dropping that to force us to use an account. If it's manufacturer specific, I'll have to be asking about it to random people who have the phone. Not an awful idea, at least. Could be worse... Thank you.